# Read in Multiple Excel Files with Different Layouts in R

Tags: r, excel, readxl, openxlsx

I have a collection of a dozen excel files I am reading in to a list of dataframes in R with the following code:

```
data_path <- "path"
files <- dir(data_path, pattern = "*.xlsx")

data <- files %>%
  map(~readWorkbook(file.path(data_path, .), sheet = "Results"))
```

This grabs everything no problems. The issue is that I need them all in the same format for further manipulation and, due to a non-universal layout, some are imported like this:

```
X1     2016     2017     2018
y       12       12       12
```

and others like this:

```
Result
y         2016       2017       2018
x          12         12         12
```

The reason is because some excel files are forwarded to me with an additional row at the top with the string character 'Results'

Now I could fix this with direct surgery to each one:

```
names(data) <- rbind(data[1,])
names(data)[1] <- "X1"
data <- data[-c(1),]
```

But this seems like a rather ugly hack solution that will lead to automation problems down the line. Is there a way to use the readWorkbook() function but specify to skip rows if they contain certain values?

eg perhaps something like:

```
if value equal to 'Result' {
  skipRow()
}
```

Or to search dataframes for rows of dates and use these as column names?

Comment: Use `filter()` from `dplyr`, and do something like `data %>% filter(firstcol != "Result")` (I'm assuming that that string is stored in the first column since you mentioned you're storing everything as data frames).

Comment: Dunois, it is stored as a column header due to being present on the first row when the data is read in. I can see where you're coming from but not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the easiest solution I can think of here is something like this.

First, import the `xlsx` files with `colNames = FALSE` like so:

```
data <- files %>%
  map(~readWorkbook(file.path(getwd(), .), sheet = "Sheet1", colNames = FALSE))
```

Now all you need to do is
- remove the **first row** if it contains "Result" in the first column
- assign each `xlsx` file to its own data frame (optional)
- set the column names for each of these files (optional)

This can be done like so:

```
for(i in 1:length(data)){
  data[[i]] %<>% filter(X1 != "Result") #Alternatively data[[i]] <- data[[i]] %>% filter(X1 != "Result")
  assign(paste0("FileName", i), as.data.frame(data[[i]]))
  names(paste0("FileName", i)) <- c("Names", "For", "Your", "Columns")
}
```

Please note the usage of the reverse pipe `%<>%` (from the package `magrittr`) in the first statement inside the for loop.

**Note**: this will remove any and all rows that contain the string "Result" in the first column.

Comment: Didn't solve the whole issue but has definitely set me on the right path, thank you. Also first time learning about the use of the reverse pipe function which has been a bonus. Only issue remaining is naming the dataframes but this is complicated due to the fact that they have different numbers of columns (not a fan of the various analysts who collected this data) but believe I can work around this by specifying the number of columns to be read in at the import level.